# NullPointerException in this simple program

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Can anyone help me?

```
package com.sample;

import java.sql.Connection;

import java.sql.DriverManager;

import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

import java.sql.ResultSet;

import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBClass {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws ClassNotFoundException,SQLException,Exception {

        Connection conn=null;

        PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        ResultSet rs=null;


        try{
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.137.30:1521:ORA10G","xxx","xxx");

            System.out.println("Before Query");
            pstmt=conn.prepareStatement("Select ROOM_NO from COHS_ROOM_ALLOTMENT where REQ_ID='RQ0011' and CUST_ID='CUS001'");
            System.out.println("Query is being executed");
            rs=pstmt.executeQuery(); 
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Room No : "+rs.getInt(1));
            }
        }catch ( ClassNotFoundException claexp ){
            throw(claexp);
        }catch ( SQLException sqlexp ){
            throw(sqlexp);
        }catch ( Exception exp ){
            throw(exp);
        }finally{
            rs.close();
            pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace?

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: check if the DB is up.

Comment: if your methos is already throwing cnfe , why  to catch it again?

Comment: I guess you need to add `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").newInstance();`

Comment: java version used? and which line is throwing the error

Comment: Please don't catch/rethrow exceptions uselessly (this destroys the original stack trace). Also, `ClassNotFoundException` and `SQLException` both inherit from `Exception`, so there's no need to list all three in the `throws` - just `throws(Exception)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
finally{
    rs.close();
    pstmt.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

should be

```
 finally{
    if(rs!=null){try{rs.close();}catch(IOException e){}}
    //...
 }
```

Comment: I think you there is an exception in sql connection, then goto finally block, the rs is null, so when invoke rs.close(), NPE is been throwing.

Answer (score 1):

If using java 7

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.24.137.30:1521:ORA10G", "xxx", "xxx");) {
    System.out.println("Before Query");
    try (PreparedStatement pstmt = conn
            .prepareStatement("Select ROOM_NO from COHS_ROOM_ALLOTMENT where REQ_ID='RQ0011' and CUST_ID='CUS001'");) {
        System.out.println("Query is being executed");
        try (ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();) {
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Room No : " + rs.getInt(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have classes12.zip in classpath.

Comment: s, classes12.jar is missing and i changed the finally by if (rs != null) rs.close();

Comment: I don't see the reasoning for your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using java 7, then prefer to use Closable Connections and resultSets. Like

```
try(Connection conn = DBManager.getConnection,Resultset ...
```

This way you wont have to face NullPointerExceptions

Comment: Is that snippet Java code?  Looks like it would not compile due to the `(` character which should be `{` instead.

Comment: Actually in Java 7, you can add a block with these brackets () after try block.. thats what I showed